# Node JS Memory leak with http request and async.eachLimit

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, memory-leaks

Im making a script to check the status of a certain domain list. Im using async to make parallel requests. I tried several values for concurrency and all always I end up with a JS heap out of memory when close to 200K requests.

I modified the http.agent values in order to avoid queues in the connections but still leaking memory.

I also removed the response listener in order to avoid problems related with no consuming the response, based on http module documentation the response must by consumed with 'data' event or res.resume(), but if no listener the response is discarded: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

Initially the domain list was located in mySQL In order to discard memory leak with the mySql lib I created a random domain generator.

This is the code:

```
const async = require('async');
const http = require('http');

let counter = 0;

const radomDomainListGenerator = function (){
    return [...Array(1000000)].map((_,i) => {
        let result = '';
        const length = '10';
        const chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        for (let i = length; i > 0; --i) {
            result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        }

        return result+='.com';
    });
};

var agent = new http.Agent;
agent.maxSockets = 1500;

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(counter);
}, 100);

const inspectDomains = function(elements) {
    async.eachLimit(
        radomDomainListGenerator(),
        1000,
        function(domainname, callback) {
            let timedOut = false;

            const options = {
                hostname: domainname,
                port: 80,
                path: '',
                agent: agent,
                method: 'HEAD',
                headers: {
                }
            };

            const req = http.request(options);

            req.on('error', (e) => {
                if (!timedOut) {
                    counter++;
                    callback();
                }
            });

            req.on('socket', function (socket) {
                socket.setTimeout(2000);
                counter++;
                socket.on('timeout', function() {
                    timedOut = true;
                    callback();
                    req.abort();
                });
            });

            req.end();
        },
        function(){
            console.log('END');
        });
};

inspectDomains();
```